# Pygame/Kivy on Android?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, 2d-games, qpython3

So, I'm programming in Python 3.2 on android (the app I'm using is QPython3) and I wonder if I could make a game/app with a graphic interface for android, using only a smartphone. Is it possible? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to programm android apps / games in qpython (not in qpython3) with kivy.

The only problem is that you can't export them as an apk file on your smartphone.

For that you need a linux PC / laptop.

**How you can programm and run your app/game:**

1. download qpython [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy&hl=de)
2. in the app go to qpypi and download kivy
3. write your first kivy programm in the qpython editor ([kivy doc](https://kivy.org/docs/))([Kivy crash course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq))

Then you have to add these lines of code above your actual code (in your main.py file) :

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:kivy
```

Then you can run your code.

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By now it's working fine, at the start I was afraid that it would run Python 2.7 :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at using Linux (a different Kernal) distro on your phone. Many will basically act as a pc, just lacking power. I'm sure there is one you can run regular Python with. Then you may also look at renpy for porting it to android, or even kivy but i'm thinking kivy would be very different than anything you have, and require learning a new language basically.

Sadly changing the OS on your phone is the only option I can think of, and probably the best. I cannot imagine any frameworks for android to be as vast as those that have been developed for PC. You may be able to find some hacked, port version of something that may help, a tool something idk.